# What happens to the data inserted into an unopen stream?

Tags: c++, stream

My intuitive feeling is that the data is thrown away entirely. I cannot seem to find a source with which to verify this suspicion.

What happens to data inserted into an unopen stream? (eg. `std::ofstream`)

Is the data discarded? Perhaps it is stored in a buffer until the stream is opened? Perhaps something else?

Comment: If the output stream is in a fail state (eg.: not open) nothing happens to the stream - the request to output/buffer data is ignored entirely.

Comment: @DieterLücking I think your comment would fit nicely in the answer box ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the standard "remarks" of all the file stream buffer methods that correspond to operations on the buffer it indicates that if `is_open() == false`, the function always fails. Failure is defined as returning `traits_type::eof()`. This special value is caught by higher-level IO functions which in turn set `std::ios_base::badbit` flag in the stream state.

Comment: So in other words if the stream isn't set as open, nothing touches the buffer. The buffer doesn't even get talked to.

Comment: That nope was ambiguous but I will assume it was an affirmative nope.

Comment: @JoshC Stream buffer operations aren't allowed to happen if there isn't an external device. The buffer is allocated but can't be touched until a connection is made.

Answer (score 1):

If the output stream is in a fail state (eg.: not open) nothing happens to the stream - the request to output/buffer data is ignored entirely.

Note: If the exception `std::ios_base::badbit` is enabled, it will be thrown.